# PHP unlink not working when using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, unlink

I have a process for deleting post entries in a PHP app. I want to delete the image associated with the post, if an image exists.

The post itself is deleted from the database successfully, but the image is not deleted from the image folder.

Here's delete_post.php:

```
    if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    if (isset($_POST['result'])) {
        if ($_POST['result'] == 'true') {
            $delete_img = $pdo->prepare("SELECT image FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
            $delete_img->execute([$post_id]);
            $img_row = $delete_img->fetch();

            $img = $img_row['image'];

            if (file_exists($img)) {
                unlink($img);
            }

            $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$post_id]);
        }
    }
}
```

...the form handler

```
    <?php include '../../inc/config.php';

if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    if (isset($_POST['result'])) {
        if ($_POST['result'] == 'true') {
            $delete_img = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
            $delete_img->execute([$post_id]);
            $img_row = $delete_img->fetch();

            $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/' .$img_row['image'];

            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                unlink($filename);
            }

            $get_gallery_img = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE post_id = ?");
            $get_gallery_img->execute([$post_id]);

            while ($row = $get_gallery_img->fetch()) {
                $galleryName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $row['file_name'];
                unlink($galleryName);
            }

            $delete_gallery = "DELETE FROM files WHERE post_id = ?";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($delete_gallery);
            $stmt->execute([$post_id]);

            $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$post_id]);
        }
    }
}
```

...and the Javascript that executes the form handler.

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#post<?=$id?>').on('click', function() {
                        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?", function(result){
                            $.post("inc/form_handlers/delete_post.php?post_id=<?=$id?>", {result:result});
                            if(result) {
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

I've tried moving the statement for deleting the image to just below the `$_GET['post_id'] if` statement, as well as just below the the `$_POST['result'] if` statement. I know it needs to be above the delete post statement since the path to the image is in the image column of the database - neither worked.

I have tried the unlink statement in another PHP file to make sure that it works - it does.  So far I haven't found where I am going wrong, but I continue to look.

Since I'm still new to both PHP  I am not sure where I should focus, or more to the point, what I am missing.

Comment: PHP cannot execute javascript methods, as javascript runs on the client and php runs on the server.  PHP can generate javascript code which can be returned to the client, and the client can then dynamically execute that code, but PHP cannot directly execute client side javascript.

Comment: @Taplar - didn't know that - thank you - great learning point - thank you!

Comment: Check your file permissions, check your PHP log for errors, check the result of your call to `unlink()`.

Comment: Thanks @miken32 - file permissions are good - forgot to mention I checked those - don't see any errors - but am looking again - not sure how to check of the call to unlink?  It worked when I tested on another PHP file.

Comment: `$result = unlink($file)` What is `$result`?

Comment: Not sure how to test that since the delete function calls a handler file ...

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else it was a path issue. Here's the final PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['post_id'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    if (isset($_POST['result'])) {
        if ($_POST['result'] == 'true') {
            $delete_img = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
            $delete_img->execute([$post_id]);
            $img_row = $delete_img->fetch();

            $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/' .$img_row['image'];

            unlink($filename);

            $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$post_id]);
        }
    }
}
```

The part to note is `$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/' .$img_row['image'];` - using document root was the missing link.

I hope this helps any with a similar issue.